# How to set vue component property based on if parent element has a specific class?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I have this stucture in my parent Component:

```
<div class="section" >
    <VRVideoPage :isActive="false"></VRVideoPage>
</div>
```

Via a third-party tool it's possible that the "section"-div gets a css class named "active" added.

I now want to toggle the ":isActive" property on the VRVideoPage component to true, whenever the active class is applied to its parent.

Is this achivable via the vue template syntax?

Comment: a class attribute is not reactive. You should get class `active` to a prop in `data` section via third-party tool. That way you can use the prop moth for class in section div and to pass to VRVideoPage

Comment: thank you @Anatoly. This pointed me in the right direction

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try like this but it is not a good practice and may not work:

```
<div class="section" >
    <VRVideoPage ref="video" :isActive="$refs.video.$el.parentNode.classList.contains('active')"></VRVideoPage>
</div>
```

Comment: If we are doing this you can shorten it to just using `$el.parentNode` (should be the root node of the component). No need for the refs. Your example should return the wrapper div (in the component) even I think.

Comment: If you shorten it in the way you propose - then `$el` will refer to the current component/template instead of the `VRVideoPage` component. We can put the ref on the outer DIV and then skip the `parentNode` - but there is no guarantee the ref will survive if some 3rd party script changes the DOM tree ...

Comment: Ehh but the div.section is same as `$el` (the root element of the component), actually the same as your `$refs.video.$el.parentNode` you select the first child and then go back up with parentNode? So that would be `$el` unless your going outside the component which i thought he wanted hence the `$el.parentNode`.

Comment: I admit that what you are saying is true - but only if the code shown is his whole template and not just an excerpt of it (because he says `I have this structure in my component` rather than `This is the template of my component`

Comment: thank you all. the parentNode was a very helpful thing.  @Anatoly 's comment under my original question pointed me in the right direction, mentioning that the class attribute is not reacive.